# Mocking with ContentCachingResponseWrapper to test Filter

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've implemented a filter which reads the response body and signs it. It uses a ContentCachingResponseWrapper:

```
@Slf4j
public class ResponseSignerFilter extends AbstractSigner implements Filter {


    public ResponseSignerFilter(....) {
//..constructor...
    }

 @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);

        final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        final ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);

        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);

       final boolean responseHasBody = responseWrapper.getContentSize() > 0;

 if (responseHasBody) {
//use body to sign:
     byte[] body = responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray()
//...more code for the signing...
            }

        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
  }

//init & destroy override methods
}
```

I want to test this filter with a simple mockito test. However mocking is not working as the ContentCachingRequestWrapper will stay empty. I tried something like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ResponseSignerFilterTest {


  @Test
    void exampleTest() throws ServletException, IOException {
        final ResponseSignerFilter filter = new ResponseSignerFilter(appPrivateKey, getJwtSettings());

        final MockHttpServletRequest req = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        req.setMethod("POST");

        final MockHttpServletResponse res = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        res.setContentType("application/json");

        final byte[] someBodyBytes = "give some body".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        final MockFilterChain filterChain = new MockFilterChain(new HttpServlet() {
            @Override
            protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
                res.getWriter().write("test-body");
                //alternative, does same thing:
                // res.getOutputStream().write("test-body".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                res.setContentLength(5);
                res.setCommitted(true);
            }
        });

        filter.doFilter(req, res, filterChain);
        
        //assertions on res
    }
}
```

The mockfilterchain does work in the sense that it writes to the response, but the wrapper says empty!

The actual implementation of the filter works, so I know this contentCacheWrapper works perfectly (if I do a postman call the app with this filter implemented). But in a simple mockito test, it fails. The FastByteArrayOutputStream in the Wrapper stays empty. How can I write to the response in such a way that the wrapper picks it up? I cannot find how the Wrapper picks up the content from the Reponse when chain.dofilter is executed.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Rick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I found that worked for me was to extend the **doFilter** method in the **MockFilterChain** class. Here's an example that will populate your response and **ContentCachingResponseWrapper**.

```
private class FakeContentFilterChain extends MockFilterChain {

 private byte[] responseContent;

 FakeContentFilterChain(byte[] fakeContentToInject) {
  this.responseContent = fakeContentToInject;
 }

 // Need to short-circuit the filter call chain to fake populate the response
 @Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
  if (arg1 instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
    final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) arg1;
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    httpServletResponse.getOutputStream().write(responseContent);
  }
 }
}
```

Then you can use it in your code as:

```
FilterChain filterChain = new FakeContentFilterChain("test-body".getBytes());
filter.doFilter(req, res, filterChain);
```

Comment: That's a nice idea I haven't tried out yet. I'll try that maybe later this week. I had to move on without a solution since I didn't have an answer for a while, but I'll look into it when I have time for it.

Comment: Awesome! Keep us posted

Comment: I finally had time to look at this project again. And yes, your solution worked perfectly! Thank you very much.

Comment: I have wasted a pretty considerable amount of time to find a way to test a filter newing up a ContentCachingResponseWrapper, but finally this little "hack" worked perfectly. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 2):

I used the similar approach to pre-write both request and response bodies for ContentCachingRequestWrapper and ContentCachingResponseWrapper respectively. It also allows to mock request, response and filter chain uniformly:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
HttpServletResponse request = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
FilterChain filterChain = mock(FilterChain.class);

doAnswer(invocation -> {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = invocation.getArgument(0);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = invocation.getArgument(1);

        ByteArrayOutputStream requestContent = (ByteArrayOutputStream) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(requestWrapper, "cachedContent");
        if (requestContent != null) {
            requestContent.write("{'request-key': 'request-value'}".getBytes());
        }
        FastByteArrayOutputStream responseContent = (FastByteArrayOutputStream) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(responseWrapper, "content");
        if (responseContent != null) {
            responseContent.write("{'response-key': 'response-value'}".getBytes());
        }
        return null;
    }).when(filterChain).doFilter(any(ServletRequest.class), any(ServletResponse.class));
```